# Как в С++ работать с БД? Посоветуйте литературу.

Tags: база-данных, c++

Здравствуйте! Возникла необходимость разработать программу, которая будет иметь возможность хранить и обрабатывать статистические данные. Как пример: школьный журнал, т.е. список учеников, их оценки и, собственно, возможно обрабатывать всю эту информацию.

Собираюсь работать на ПО в VS C++. Я так понимаю, что нужно работать с базой данных. И вот собственно мой вопрос: не могли бы мне посоветовать какую-нибудь литературу по этому поводу, ссылки? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MySQL](http://www.softtime.ru/cpp/read.php?id_forum=1&id_theme=22), так же нужны библиотеки мускула, всё можно подёргать из исходников на офф сайте.

Comment: Спасибо большое, уже начал разбираться в исходниках. 

Буду благодарен если кто-нибудь ещё подкинет любую информацию по данной теме.

Comment: это только мускул, вообще бд надо выбтрать под конкретные требования. прошу прошения за ошибки, у меня рука одна поавреждена

Answer (score 0):

Работа из Си с PostgreSQL: глянь тут http://postgresql.ru.net/docs/develc.html.
В целом все довольно просто.